# How to handle 404 request in Django?

Tags: django, django-errors

I am trying to handle 404 requests when the page is not found. I am getting an error as **Server Error (500)**.

Here is the code :

In settings.py

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

In myapp.views:

```
def handle_not_found(request, exception):
    return render(request, "404.html")
```

In project urls.py :

```
handler404 = "myapp.views.handle_not_found"
```

Error on Browser :

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/requested_page

Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

URLs shows here...

The current path, requested_page, didn’t match any of these.
```

Comment: Show us the full stack trace for the error.

Comment: On my console I am getting as 
[26/Apr/2022 11:38:26] "GET /requested_url HTTP/1.1" 500 145

requesteted_url is path entered in browser

Comment: That isn't sufficient to help - we need to see the full stack trace, which if you are running with `DEBUG=True` will be displayed in the browser.

Comment: Check errors that I got on the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting this error because the template which I render through 404 handers has an error.

I have fixed that error and now it working fine.